# Scan barcode from Iphone Keyboard

Tags: iphone, inventory

I am using an online based inventory tracking system called Tracmor. I'm wondering if there's an app for Iphone or some feature that allows you to scan barcodes from your iphone keyboard. The way I am able to input data inventory data into tracmor is by selecting the field in the Tracmor online portal, which pulls up the iphone keyboard. Ideally, I would like to scan the bar code from this point for the field. I know this is possible for android, but I have not found the solution for iphone. I am currently using an Iphone6.

Thank you,
Maya

Answer (score 1):

I am using BarcodeKey from the app store - it works like a keyboard.  it seems to work well for our use - scanning barcode data into a web form/field.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Noah and I am a support engineer with Tracmor.

I wanted to let you know that there is an iPhone app that will support scanning barcodes into Tracmor.

Please see the app called "Barcode Scan to Web" By Berry Wing LLC in the iTunes store for more information.

With this app you will be able to scan bar codes with the camera on your iPhone directly into the text fields in Tracmor for items such as asset tags, locations, and users.